# PHP code with a variable in the same row

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to make my files as small as possible and wonder why the following php code works in my Wordpress Installation

```
<?php 
    $mark_count = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_post_mark_count', true);
?>
```

and the following (same) php code not

```
<?php $mark_count = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_post_mark_count', true); ?>
```

When i put the code in one row, my site gets blank. No Error or else in the firebug console. It is a new WP Installation and there is no conflict between plugins. The installation is on a Apache Server and runs the latest PHP 7 version. Any idea how to fix this problem or why this happens?

Comment: @deceze - im new, sorry for my mistake. I edited my question... Is it ok this way? best

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does that mean? What does or doesn't it do? Error messages? If so, what? If not, how exactly do you conclude that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @deceze - better now?

Comment: Check your error logs and/or enable error reporting. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851/476

Comment: I bet it is a problem with the file encoding or line endings.